# Enabling SMTP Basic Authentication on Office365-Tenant after 1st Oct 2022

Tags: azure, smtp, office365

I understand that SMTP Basic Authentication on Office365-Tenants [will be automatically disabled from the 1st October 2022 on](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437). As SMPT Oauth 2.0 Client Credential Flow [has not been implement yet by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#smtp-protocol-exchange) we can't move our product implementation (non-interactive) away from Basic Authentication.

We therefore need our customers to be able to keep SMTP Basic Authentication enabled after the 1st. October.

Question:

- Will existing Office365-Tenants be able to keep SMTP with Basic Authentication enabled until Oauth 2.0 Client Credential Flow will be available for SMTP?
- Is the same also true for new Tenants that are created in future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP basic auth is not going away yet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online#pop-imap-and-smtp-auth (last paragraph of this section)

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-september-2021-update/ba-p/2772210 (Bolded line after the first paragraph)

Comment: URL only answers are discouraged here. Please provide a summary or more details since in the future the websites linked might not be available.